# Using three-phase contactor with single-phase motor

Tags: ac, three-phase, single-phase, contactor

If using a contactor for three- phase motors with a single-phase motor, can just the hot (120 V) line be passed through the contactor, with the neutral and ground bypassing it? I believed the concept for circuit breakers is applicable in this case too.

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: You can switch neutral with it too but never switch the ground / earth wire.

Comment: For clarification, with a device using a hot, neutral, and ground wire, there is no danger in leaving the neutral wire unbroken? My conclusion was that this only poses a risk if two devices share a common neutral.

Comment: Current UL regulations require that neutral be disconnected from AC line power as well as each phase. Ground is NEVER disconnected.

Comment: When a single phase motor is to be controlled using a three phase contactor and bimetal overload relay, the line is to be wired through 2 contacts in series and the neutral through the third.

This is covered in detail at  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/463051/does-only-wiring-2-poles-of-a-3-pole-overload-relay-have-any-effect

Comment: @vu2nan If an overload relay is not being used then this wouldn't be necessary, correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, the life of the contactor contacts would increase should all three contacts be used.

Answer (score 2):

When a single-phase motor is to be controlled using a three-phase contactor and a bimetal overload relay, the line is wired through two contacts in series and the neutral through the third.

This is covered in detail at [Does only wiring 2 poles of a 3 pole overload relay have any effect?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/463051/does-only-wiring-2-poles-of-a-3-pole-overload-relay-have-any-effect)